# Coffee machine on solar powered current

Tags: power, watts

I would like to have a Nespresso (capsule) coffee machine powered by a solar panel. This might sound a bit crazy, but I'm not sure it must be:

- This capsule coffee machine runs on a 12V car cigarette lighter: https://www.handpresso.com/en/handpresso-auto-capsule-8.html
- There are USB-to-cigarette-lighter converters which convert the 5V USB current to 12V car cigarette lighter.
- A large USB solar panel should do the rest, possibly with a USB power bank.

I would like to know whether this actually works, before buying all the stuff.

One consideration is power. The coffee machine linked above draws 120 Watts, and I'm pretty sure that most USB current sources don't supply 120 Watts. I did read that there is a USB mode called Power Delivery (PD) which supports up to 240 Watts of power.

How can I make sure that my setup will actually work? Can I combine power banks to make sure there is enough power? Are there power banks supplying 12V car cigarette lighter current?

Comment: Power delivery works by the USB power source and the device negotiating with each other to agree on a higher voltage than 5V.  A simple 5V to 12V adaptor won't do that.  And 120W at 5V is 24A, way too much for USB.

Comment: There are 12 V solar panels. Remember that the rated output of a solar panel will be with very bright sunshine. It might be better to store up that energy over some time with a battery than expect to use the panel in the early morning.

Comment: @SimonB I just saw that the coffee machine also supports 24V. So, with the maximum USB current of 5A, I have the required 120W. But you're of course right, I need the right adapter that negotiates 24V USB and passes those 24V on to the cigarette lighter.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, a USB cable would never handle the current required to operate your coffee machine. Not even close! Even if multiple power bank could theoretically do it, combining those cheap devices with no protection at all will most likely allow you to roast your bean too. If you must use those battery banks, I would open them and take only the cell and use an external regulator.

I think a better approach is to use LiPo batteries as the one used in RC cars or drills with an external DC-DC converter. Always consider that each boost converter cost a significant amount of power. Therefore, you want to be as close as possible (voltage wise) with your cells.

Regarding the solar panel idea, solar panels are not regulated power supply. They don't react well to current inrush. Without knowledge on how solar cell works, my advise would be to charge a battery using solar panel, then disconnect the solar panel and connect your coffee maker after.

In short, my advice is, use battery without regulator and find a DC-DC converter that can convert the voltage from your batteries to the 12V required by your coffee maker. Then to charge those battery, you might use a solar panel, but find yourself a controller and never plug both the coffee maker and solar panel at the same time.

Be careful, this setup will heat up!

Comment: Thanks. Thinking again of it, I could maybe buy a 12V car battery (sulfuric acid) to power the coffee machine, and charge that battery with the solar panel. Agree?

Comment: Yes, that would be much more straight forward!